# Failing at scheduling code

Tags: python, scheduler, chatbot

I'm trying to make my chatbot to send a message every day at a specific time but I'm failing at it. do you see what is wrong in my code ?

The function I'm trying to run is the "send message"

```
import schedule
import time

def daily_message():
  msg = "Hello Everyone, I'm a bot, please use me to notify people that need things on this channel. Right now, you can type @Ditto: Rob and Jackie, @Ghost: Rob @Rare: Mitch, Corey, Abhinay, Sabre, Sam-B @Quest: Mitch, Corey, Abhinay. Contact Corey to be added or deleted from a list " 
  usrID= 0,0
  locid= [0, 0],[0, 0]
  send_message(msg, usrID, locid)


schedule.every().day.at("20:18").do(daily_message)
schedule.every().day.at("20:04").send_message(daily_message)


while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```

Thanks have a good day

PS: here is the complete code: https://github.com/coreyboulet/testbot

PPS: I'm really new in coding, my appologies if this is a dumb question but I was not able to find or make work anything found on internet

Comment: Please format your code. Control-K while highlighting it.

Comment: Thank you Pavel for the formating, sorry about that.

Comment: What's failing? Is it just not triggering, or are you getting an error message or something?

Comment: Good question Daniel, when I start the bot it will send the message 4 times in a row and become totally unresponsive (as soon as I start the bot)